# Fitting data to arange using python

Tags: python, range

I am having problem fitting the following data to a range of `0.1-1.0`:

```
t=[0.23,0.76,0.12]
```

Obviously each item in the t-list falls within the range `0.1-1.0`, but the output of my code indicates the opposite.

My attempt

```
import numpy as np
>>> g=np.arange(0.1,1.0,0.1)
>>> t=[0.23,0.76,0.12]
>>> t2=[x for x in t if x in g]
>>> t2
[]

Desired output:[0.23,0.76,0.12]
```

I clearly understand that using an interval of `0.1` will make it difficult to find any of the t-list items in the specified arange. Could have made some adjustment but my range is fixed and my data is large which makes it practically impossible to keep adjust the range.

Any suggestions on how to get around this? thanks

Comment: What's wrong with "0.1 <= x < 1.0"?

Comment: if thats what he actually wants... his code does something very different

Comment: jhermann, you just hit the nail on the head, I would prefer 0.1<=x<=1.0. Please try and fit it into the the code and lets see the output. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to inspect `g`?

```
>>> g
array([ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9])
```

So clearly none of your elements is in g.

Probably, you look for something like

```
>>> [x for x in t if 0.1<=x<=1.0]
[0.23, 0.76, 0.12]
```

Comment: I was gonna ask why he would expect those to be in the list in a comment but meh nice answer

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes, it is unclear what OP wants, mainly due to third 0.1 in range definition

Comment: hi alko, thanks for the answer, I clearly stated in the code that the issue is the interval (0.1), and that my interval cannot be adjusted given the size of my data.

Comment: however, I still need to use the arange and the interval to search automatically over a large dataset. Hence the question is still unanswered.

Comment: @Tiger1 can you clarify what you need with more examples of fitting/not fitting values, what part of your question is not answered? ans is your dataset numpy's based array or base python list? It is totally unclear what you **exactly** need.

Comment: @alko, my dataset is a python list, but I'm using numpy arrays to speed up the search. Your method works, but there is an issue I'm still trying to figure out why its not working as aspected with my dataset.

Comment: @Tiger1 so you have two options, to provide complete dataset with your issue, and second to come back with a small sample dataset when you'll be able to locate your issue. My crystall ball says it can be related to float precision or smthng alike, but it's a raw guess